# Incompatible types Android Studio error

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I've created a function and I get an error in the return statement, why?

```
import android.app.Fragment;
@Override
public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(DeviceFragment.DescriptionKey,deviceDescription[position]);
    bundle.putInt(DeviceFragment.ImageIDKey, getDeviceImageID(position));

    DeviceFragment deviceFragment = new DeviceFragment();
    deviceFragment.setArguments(bundle);

    return deviceFragment;
```

Error:

```
Error:(38, 16) incompatible types
found   : com.example.sergiumereuta.swipeviewtest.DeviceFragment
required: android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

Comment: Right, so presumably your `DeviceFragment` type doesn't extend `Fragment`...

Answer (score 3):

I think is because you are using Fragment, and support Fragment at same time.

If you override android.app.Fragment getItem(int position) instead of android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position).

It's probably because DeviceFragment extends android.app.Fragment and not android.support.v4.app.Fragment